# Setting Map Annotation with an Image in Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, annotations, maps

I'm trying to change the map annotation to a custom image that i made in a static cell. The map's annotation works but then when i try to put my image in the map zooms to the location but doesn't display the image.

```
     import UIKit
            import MapKit
            import CoreLocation


        class ContactsTableViewController: UITableViewController, MKMapViewDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    }

     override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()


        self.addressMap.delegate = self
    }

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ContactCell", for: indexPath) as! customCell

            if let _ = currentAnnotation {
                addressMap.removeAnnotation(currentAnnotation!)
            }


            let contact = contacts.contactWithIndex((indexPath as NSIndexPath).row)
            print(contact)
            cell.nameLabel.text = contact.name
            cell.addressLabel.text = contact.address

            let country = "USA"
            let city = "Cicero"
            let street = contact.address

            // Create Address String
            let address = "\(country), \(city), \(street)"

            // Geocode Address String
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) { (placemarks, error) in
                // Process Response
                self.processResponse(withPlacemarks: placemarks, error: error)
                var location: CLLocation?

                if let placemarks = placemarks, placemarks.count > 0 {
                    location = placemarks.first?.location
                }

                if let location = location {
                    let coordinate = location.coordinate
                    print("Custom cell: \(coordinate.latitude), \(coordinate.longitude)")

                    //Drops pin to current MKPointAnnotationis logged in
                    self.currentAnnotation = MKPointAnnotation()
                    self.currentAnnotation?.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate.latitude, longitude: coordinate.longitude)

                    let image1 = CustomPointAnnotation()
                    image1.imageName = "mapPin.png"
                    self.addressMap.addAnnotation(image1)

                    //Pins the location on the mapview
                    //cell.addressMap.addAnnotation(self.currentAnnotation!)
                    cell.addressMap.addAnnotation(image1)
                    //Auto zoom into user location
                    let span = MKCoordinateSpanMake(0.02, 0.02)
                    let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: (self.currentAnnotation?.coordinate)!, span: span)
                    cell.addressMap.setRegion(region, animated: true)

                } else {
                    print("No Matching Location Found")
                }
            }
    }


 func addressMap(_ addressMap: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        if !(annotation is CustomPointAnnotation) {
           return nil
        }

        let reuseId = "test"
        var anView = addressMap.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseId)
        if anView == nil {
            anView = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
            anView?.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            anView?.annotation = annotation
        }

        //Set annotation-specific properties **AFTER**
        //the view is dequeued or created...

        let cpa = annotation as! CustomPointAnnotation
        anView?.image = UIImage(named:cpa.imageName)

        return anView
        }
```

Here's the class for the annotation

```
 import UIKit
import MapKit

class CustomPointAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    var imageName: String!

}
```

If anyone can tell me what I'm doing wrong that's causing my image to not display as the annotation that would be awesome.

Comment: You don't appear to ever set the `coordinate` of the `CustomPointAnnotation`.

Comment: When I set the `coordinate` to `image1.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(42, -84)` then it shows the originally pin and not my `"mapPin.png"`

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues:

1. You don't appear to ever set the `coordinate` of the `CustomPointAnnotation`.
2. The signature for the [`mapView(_:viewFor:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/mapkit/mkmapviewdelegate/1452045-mapview) is incorrect. If you add a breakpoint in your method, you'll see it is not called. Your map outlet may be called `addressMap`, but the delegate method name is `mapView(_:viewFor:)`, regardless of the name of your `MKMapView` outlet reference.